# How to create sci-fi panels using modifiers?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I want to create sci-fi panels using modifiers so i can keep the original mesh.

Comment: You know that i have answered myself to give an explanation with one picture after seeing that they were only youtube videos ?

Comment: Ah yes apologies, missed that, comment removed. Had already upvoted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark the sharp edges where you want to apply the separation, then add an Edge Split modifier, a Solidify and a Bevel modifiers.

[image]